# SQL: can i have a table A with a composite primary key cpk, composed by a unique attribute and a foreign key? If so, is a bad practice?

Tags: database, plsql

I have a table FILE_HISTORY that represents different versions of a file excel ( file1version1.excel, file1version2.excel etc..)with these columns:

```
file_id NUMBER,
version NUMBER,
data TIMESTAMP(6),
user VARCHAR2(50)

foreign key (file_id) references FILE(id)
```

What i want is to ensure that the couple (file_id, version) is unique. The problem is that file_id should be a foreign key to another table FILE which has the ID of the file and not the version (file1.excel, file2.excel);

so is correct to use the couple (file_id, version) as a composite primary key for table FILE_HISTORY (note that file_id is a foreign key while version is not)? and how is possible in pl sql?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As long as the column in the table you are referencing has a primary key or unique constraint, then you should be fine, e.g. the following works:

```
create table t1 (c1 number,
                 c2 varchar2(1),
                 c3 date,
                 constraint t1_pk primary key (c1));

create table t2 (c1 number,
                 c2 varchar2(1),
                 c3 varchar2(1),
                 constraint t2_pk primary key (c1, c2),
                 constraint t2_fk foreign key (c1) references t1 (c1));

insert into t1 (c1, c2, c3)
select 1 c1, 'a' c2, sysdate-10 c3 from dual union all
select 2 c1, 'b' c2, sysdate-8.4 c3 from dual union all
select 3 c1, 'c' c2, sysdate-3.65 c3 from dual;

insert into t2 (c1, c2, c3)
select 1 c1, 'x' c2, 'g' c3 from dual union all
select 1 c1, 'y' c2, 'h' c3 from dual union all
select 2 c1, 'y' c2, 'i' c3 from dual union all
select 3 c1, 'x' c2, 'j' c3 from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i'll give it a try

Comment: Foreign keys can only link to column(s) in a primary key or unique key constraint. If your situation is the same as that of my test case, you won't have any problems. However, if you were to try to do a foreign key from t1.c1 to t2.c1, that would fail, since t2.c1 does not have a primary key or unique constraint upon it, even though it is part of a multi-column primary key. If you think about it, that makes sense, since you should expect that a child record must have only a single parent record (but each parent record can have multiple child records).